# How can I update/change the base_url of pagination in CodeIgniter?

Tags: php, codeigniter

I'm new to CodeIgniter. I have populated some categories to a view, and the category ID is passing through the URL to the controller then to the model.

I also need to integrate the pagination. For that I have done the base_url like so:

```
$config['base_url'] = base_url() . "kc_directory/categoryloader/";
```

But when I click on the pagination link, it's returning the following link:

```
localhost/kc_directory/categoryloader/2
```

When I modify the above link to `localhost/kc_directory/categoryloader/2/?value1=1` it works, where `value1` is the variable name and `1` is the category ID.

How do I change the `base_url` to achieve this ?

Answer (score 0):

Change base url settings

config it like

```
$config['base_url'] = 'http://example.com/';
```

if you work in localhost

config it like

```
$config['base_url']= 'http://localhost/YourFolderName/';
```

Comment: what is difference?

Comment: @razibalmamun i just explain how to set base url in live server and localhost, is that bad practice??

Comment: Thanks bibin, sorry for the confusion. actually the base_url works, what i need is adding ?value1=1 after the pagination offset. ie the new url should be like "localhost/kc_directory/categoryloader/2/?value1=1". In the initial page load everything works, but when we click on the pagination links, link changed to "localhost/kc_directory/categoryloader/2" and second page is not showing. If we edit it like localhost/kc_directory/categoryloader/2/?value=1" it shows.. Hope its clear

Answer (score 0):

You can customize your base url in `application/config/config.php`:

```
$config['base_url'] = 'https://hostname.com/';
```

Comment: Thanks wolfgang, sorry for the confusion. actually the base_url works, what i need is adding ?value1=1 after the pagination offset. ie the new url should be like "localhost/kc_directory/categoryloader/2/?value1=1"

Answer (score 0):

Thank you guys.. fixed....

$config['suffix'] = '/?value1='.$value1;
$this->pagination->initialize($config);

This worked...

Thanks :)